# Jquery trigger subbmit not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code written in JavaScript file and i am calling this funtion 'onclick' event of button from JSP page. This function should calls an struts action on button click

```
function savedata(type)
{
    $('#ajaxLoad').removeClass('displayNone');
    $('#btnType').val(type);
    $('#Form').attr('action','saveTemplate.action');
    $('#Form').trigger('submit');

    if(!$('.error').is(':visible'))
    {
        $("#btnActivate").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        self.parent.tb_remove();
        self.parent.eventManagement(); 
        self.parent.$('#EventSaveSuccess').removeClass('displayNone');

    }
    $('#ajaxLoad').addClass('displayNone');
}
```

above works perfectly fine in Mozilla and IE but fails in Chrome

if i put an alter('') just before triggering the submit then some time chrome calls that action but fails most of the time..
Need your help guys..

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you check the console in Chrome after clicking the button do you see any errors? Also, could you please post the code which calls this function.

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: `self.parent.$('#EventSaveSuccess').removeClass('displayNone');`is it this line?

Comment: Do you cancel the default action of the button?

Comment: <input type="button" id="btnSave" name="save" onclick = "savedata('btnSave');" value="<s:text name="rolemanagement.save"/>" class="button" /> this code calls the function

Comment: @adiga  I don't see any error on console...
epascarello... no i haven't canceled any action of button

Comment: @JotibaBuwa you can just add all the code below `$('#Form').attr()` in a `setTimeout` and check. `setTimeout(function() { $('#Form').trigger('submit'); ...if(){}... $('#ajaxLoad').addClass('displayNone');}, 500)`

Comment: @adiga ..Thanks for your help.. I tried you solution..but that works only for the first time and failing there after..

Answer (score 1):

What i observed is that it needed time to submit the action in chrome, but it worked for other browsers. so I have added setTimeout() after submitting the action..and it worked in all browsers..
@Adiga given me solution but i made little change in that, and it worked for me. Below is changed working code. Thank you all for your suggestions and help :)

```
function savedata(type)
{
    $('#ajaxLoad').removeClass('displayNone');
    $('#btnType').val(type);
    $('#ConfigureEmailForm').attr('action','saveTemplate.action');
    $('#ConfigureEmailForm').trigger('submit');

    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!$('.error').is(':visible'))
        {
            $("#btnActivate").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $("#btnSave").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            self.parent.tb_remove();
            self.parent.eventManagement(); 
            self.parent.$('#EventSaveSuccess').removeClass('displayNone');

        }
        $('#ajaxLoad').addClass('displayNone');
        },500);
}
```